# Add class to every child div based on index

Tags: jquery

I need to target and add a class (ie. "-show") to the nth child of **all** elements with a certain class. The nth child needs to be in the form of a variable (ie. :nth-child(i)).

I tried using `eq()` but it seems to only affect the children of the first element of the selected class.

`jQuery('.text-wrapper > div').eq(1).addClass('-show');`

Also tried to incorporate `each()` without any luck:

`jQuery('.text-wrapper > div').eq(1).each(function(){ jQuery(this).addClass('-show'); });`

The result im looking for is:

```
<div class="text-wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div class="-show"></div>
</div>

<div class="text-wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div class="-show"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`:nth-child(2)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo) should do it:

```js
$(".text-wrapper > *:nth-child(2)").addClass("-show");
```

```css
.-show {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper">
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
</div>

<div class="text-wrapper">
  <div>first</div>
  <div>second</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) didn't work because it just grabs the element at the given index in the jQuery set.

Comment: This works when I provide an exact index, but I should have mentioned the index needs to be a variable. Is it possible to use that selector with a variable included? (ie. $(".text-wrapper > *:nth-child(`NUMBER`)").addClass("-show");

Comment: @Scribble_Scratch - String concatenation: `$(".text-wrapper > *:nth-child(" + number + ")").addClass("-show");` :-)